# Ruby on Rails 3: How to find associated records through associated method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Invoices with many Items and Payments.

This is my Invoice model (at least a part of it):

```
def total
  items.sum { |item| item.total }
end

def balance
  self.payments.sum(:amount) - self.total
end
```

Now in the Payment view I am trying to find all the Invoices with a balance less than 0:

```
<%= f.select(:invoice_id, current_user.invoices.where("balance > ?", 0)) %>
```

This doesn't work of course, because *balance* is not a column. But how can I insert a method there?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options. You could always make `balance` a column (updating it as appropriate when payments or items are added), which will allow you do this sort of query efficiently.

You could, however, just use a plain Ruby approach - specifically, [`Array#select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-select). Something like

```
current_user.invoices.to_a.select {|invoice| invoice.balance < 0}
```

would get you there. It wouldn't be very efficient if users have a large number of invoices though.

**Update**: also, you're going to hit an [N+1 query situation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) if you do it like this, because each invoice will need to retrieve its items and payments from the database. To avoid this, you need to include the items and payments in the original query like so:

```
current_user.invoices.includes(:items, :payments).to_a.select{ ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, Andy! Will try your suggestion. But is this really so inefficient? If I store the balance in the database, won't that be "redundant data" because it can be calculated using two other table columns? I am new to Ruby and Rails, so I wonder how the pros do it. Right now, I am trying to use virtual attributes wherever I can. Not sure if this is good though...

Comment: It's going to be pretty inefficient. Firstly, you return all invoices, when you are only interested in a few - that's going to slow down your query and waste some memory. Secondly, to recalculate the balance each time, you have to loop over all payments and all items for all the invoices, which will cost a few cpu cycles. So it's going to be a performance hit - how bad it is depends on the number of invoices per user, and how often you do the calculation.

Comment: Also, best practice is to avoid putting logic in the view. You could do the query in the controller, and use instance variables to pass the result down to the view, then you can do `<%= f.select(:invoice_id, @outstanding_invoices) %>`. Even better, you could make `outstanding_invoices` a method on the user model.

Comment: OK, so if I have an index view of all a user's invoices showing each invoice's (calculated) balance and total, it's probably better to convert those two virtual attributes into table columns...?

Comment: Yep, in this case that's what I would do. Virtual attributes are great but only when calculating them isn't too expensive - e.g. putting a `full_name` together from a `first_name` and a `last_name`.